# Delay Keypress until TextBox is enabled

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox, keypress

My custom Control displays a TextBox when a key is pressed (basically to allow for numeric input). It's easy enough to show the TextBox from inside the KeyDown event on the main control, but how do I pump the keypress into the textbox?

Comment: Can't you just set the focus to the new TextBox? http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10074071/set-focus-on-text-box-when-loading-winform.aspx

Comment: @bzlm, setting focus to the textbox /after/ the keypress means that first keydown event is missing. Thus when I start typing "3.25" in order to specify numeric input, the "3" will be missing as that one was eaten by the UserControl and I end up with ".25"

Comment: Well, can't you set focus to it earlier?

Comment: @bzlm, earlier when? At what point do I know that the user is about to start typing?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you keep a buffer ( a variable) to store the value of KeyPress and after the TextBox is Enabled, update the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the KeyValue of the KeyEventArgs parameter (sent to the method handling the keydown event of your user control).

Using that you can send the first key to the textbox and then move the focus to the textbox like suggested before.

Hope I understood you well.